# Is there a way we can get date alone from a datetime field stored as string in MongoDB. We are using Spring MongoDB driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say I have an date attribute stored in the format dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss i.e. 22/12/2021 10:15:23. Now I just want 22/12/2021 as a date value so that I can do date comparisons. I want this operation to happen at database itself so that I can do date comparisons as part of the query/aggregation itself. Please note I am using Spring MongoDB driver.

Comment: You can use the Aggregation Date Operators to convert string date data to Date objects, compare, perform arithmetic operations, etc. As such you can compare the date data including the time part of it.

Comment: I have used the aggregation operation $dateFromString but that converts the String attribute (stored in datetime format) to an ISODate which bears both date as well as timestamp. Now let's take a case wherein my input will be just a date and I want to do equality operation, how do I achieve it?

Comment: In such case you have to figure what works for your use case. Those are tools available, and rest is your particular situation.

Comment: Can you please suggest what should be the approach here now that you are aware about the situation I am citing. A sample code snippet would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Getting date alone from a datetime string is not possible in MongoDB since it always returns an ISO date with time. As a workaround we can convert the time HH:mm:ss to 00:00:00 either by applying String operations on the string attribute or by using Arithmetic operations on the date. We will have to add a temporary field in the query which will hold the converted value using add field operations. And then we can compare them with a given date.